# Google API Autofill doesen't work when modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

technologies used: coldfusion, jquery.

Hello as the title says, i'm trying to implement google API on a modal, the error i'm encountering is the following:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
> at initAutocomplete

i have 2 files where im working on:

1. the one that includes my modal where i set up scripts for google api :

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete&language=it&output=json&key=MYKEY" defer></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2)the modal itself containing this part of code :

```
let autocomplete;
let address1Field;
let address2Field;
let postalField;

function initAutocomplete() {
    let getnazione =  document.querySelector("##nazione");
    let setdefaultnation = $( "##nazione" ).val();
    address1Field = document.querySelector("##indirizzo");
    address2Field = document.querySelector("##citta");
    postalField = document.querySelector("##cap");

    $('##nazione').on('select2:select', function () {
        console.log("ciao");
        console.log(getnazione.value);
        autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({ country: [getnazione.value] });

    });
    
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(address1Field, {
        componentRestrictions: { country: [setdefaultnation] },
        fields: ["address_components", "name"],
        types: ["address"],
    });
    /* address1Field.focus(); */
    // When the user selects an address from the drop-down, populate the
    // address fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", fillInAddress );
}

function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    let indirizzo = "";
    let cap = "";
    let civicnumber="";

    // Get each component of the address from the place details,
    // and then fill-in the corresponding field on the form.
    // place.address_components are google.maps.GeocoderAddressComponent objects
    // which are documented at http://goo.gle/3l5i5Mr
    for (const component of place.address_components) {
        // @ts-ignore remove once typings fixed
        const componentType = component.types[0];

        switch (componentType) {
            case "street_number": {
                civicnumber = `${component.long_name}`;                 
                break;
                
            }
            case "route": {
                indirizzo_corto = component.short_name;
                indirizzo_lungo = component.long_name;
                indirizzo += component.long_name;
                break;
            }
    
            case "postal_code": {
                cap = `${component.long_name}${cap}`;
                break;
            }
    
            /* case "postal_code_suffix": {
                postcode = `${postcode}-${component.long_name}`;
                break;
            } */
            case "locality":
                document.querySelector("##citta").value = component.long_name;
                break;
    
            case "administrative_area_level_2": {
                document.querySelector("##prov").value = component.short_name;
                $('##prov').trigger('change');
                break;
            }
                
            case "administrative_area_level_1": {
                document.querySelector("##stato_usa").value = component.short_name;
                $('##stato_usa').trigger('change');
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    if(civicnumber != ""){
        $("##civicnumberalert").addClass("d-none");
        /* address1Field.value = indirizzo+", "+civicnumber; */
    }
    else{
        /* address1Field.value = indirizzo; */
        $("##civicnumberalert").removeClass("d-none");
    }
    
    indirizzo_nome = place.name.replace(indirizzo_corto,indirizzo_lungo);
    address1Field.value = indirizzo_nome;
    
    postalField.value = cap;
    // After filling the form with address components from the Autocomplete
    // prediction, set cursor focus on the second address line to encourage
    // entry of subpremise information such as apartment, unit, or floor number.
    /* address2Field.focus(); */
}

window.initAutocomplete = initAutocomplete;


document.getElementById("form_sped").onkeypress = function(e) {
    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;     
    if (key == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

basically the problem i'm encoutering is that im doing 2 API call in these 2 files , and i think this is the reason of this conflict but at this point i'm not sure.

i tried moving my scripts , including them in both files or separate, also i removed async attribute from the script.

Comment: What has this question got to do with ColdFusion?